# "Sign in with Slack" keeps prompting user for permission every time

Tags: single-sign-on, slack, slack-api

I'm doing the Slack integration for my website, including allowing users to log in using the "Sign in with Slack" button. Ideally I would expect it only asks users to grant the `identity.*` permissions once, then next times when they click "Sign in with Slack", the authorization screen should only flashes then redirect to the next step (like with Facebook for example), but it keeps showing the authorization screen and users have to click the "Continue" button to grant the permission again and again. This is inconvenient for our users. Is there any way to make it prompting only once like Facebook? FYI my app is not publicly distributed to App Directory yet, could it be the reason?

Comment: Did you determine if it was due to the app not being published? I'm also having this problem, likewise only asking for `identity.basic` during login as specified in the docs (https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack)

Comment: It was not due to the app not being published, there was no way to avoid that confirmation screen, at least back then. I'm not sure if Slack has changed it until now.

Comment: It still seems to ask for permission every time you login. Quite disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

No, it has nothing to do with being in the public App directory.

Slack Sign-in does not cache user logins like other OAuth providers doe, so if you want to avoid that users have to sign-in every time you have to cache user permissions in your app. e.g. by using cookies.

Here is how it works in principle:

1. After a user signed in successfully, store the information about that successful login in the cookie for that client.
2. When a client opens you web page again, check the cookie of that client for information about a successful login.
3. When you find the information show the user belonging to that client as logged-in (instead of showing the Slack Sign-in button).
4. Show an option for logged-in users to log out (optional)

What information you store about the user depends on what you application needs. If you just want proof about a successful login it should be enough to store the `team_id` and `user_id`. But you will also receive a new `access_token` for that user (not the same as the `access_token` for your app) as result from a successful login. (see below for a full example of what you receive from Slack)

Please keep in mind that cookies are stored locally on the client and can be viewed the user. So depending on your security needs it would be advisable not store any user related information (especially not the `access_token`) in the cookie directly. Instead store an ID that links to that data stored on the server by your app. (there are other approaches to this problem. but that is a different discussion)

Here is an example of what your receive from Slack after a successful login:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "access_token": "XXXX",
    "scope": "identity.basic",
    "user": 
    {
        "id": "U12345678",
        "name": "Donald Dummy"
    }
    "team": 
    {
        "id": "T12345678"
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you suggest me to cache? I have auth token for our own site but caching it means keeping user logged in, and this is the case when they're logged out and want to log back in. The slack's authorization code is only valid within 10 minutes so caching them wouldn't work. The access token is stored in the db but user must give some proof (authorization code) for their identity again to be able to use that access token.

Comment: So what I expect is that after the first time user grants the identity permissions, next times when user clicks on the "Sign in with Slack" button, they should still be brought to slack's oauth page, where slack would check and see that this user has already granted us the `identity.*` permission, and return a new authorization code to our redirect_uri immediately without showing the screen and having user to click "Continue". What do I need to do to achieve that behaviour, or is it even possible?

Comment: to be clear: Slack will not cache user sign-ins for you, you have to implement that in your app by yourself. see my answer on how it works in principle.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question, but sorry this is not what I asked. I've already had a way to store user's "logged in" status with a JWT token, so it's not what I'm concerning about. What I meant was that when user logs out and then logs in again using "Sign in with Slack" button, they have to go to slack's authorization screen and click "Continue" again, while I expect it to be like Facebook, skipping the screen and grant the authorization immediately without asking user to click a button again.

Comment: However after looking to Slack API docs and other Slack app, I think it's not possible with Slack API at the moment so I would accept the current behavior for now.

Comment: I understand that you are looking for a switch or hack that allows you to change the behavior for Slack Sign-in to be like the one from Facebook. But as I explained in my answer that is not possible. So I gave you the only other solution to achieve the behavior you wanted. Which I detailed after you appeared to not know exactly how it would work, when you said "What do you suggest me to cache?".

Comment: The API doc does say that they won't unnecessary approvals. Check this out:

(See the section 'Sign in again and again'):
https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack

Comment: Is this still the case in 2019?
Because the documentation says: `"If the user is simply signing in to resume an existing relationship with your Slack app, we'll send them to your redirect URL right away."`

that tells me it should be automatic like facebook and others do but it isnt.... 

Comment: I'm having this issue too. The documentation page even contradicts itself, under "Token negotiation flow" it says "On subsequent logins, we'll provide an accelerated version of the approval process, still requiring a click, and then send the user back to your redirect." But for me, the screen looks like it did the first time I connected.